# Organizing Eclipse plugin/feature/update site project in SVN

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin

I need some recommendation on how to organize Eclipse Plugin/Feature/Update Site projects in SVN. I have following Eclipse projects:

```
Plug-in 1
Feature 1
Plug-in 2
Feature 2
Update Site
```

Here are some additional information:

- Feature 1 is a feature for Plug-in 1, and so on, obviously.
- Both plugins are part of one product but can be selectively installed by checking or unchecking the desired feature from the Install New Software dialog.

I am wondering if all these project should be under the "trunk" or each one should have a "branch/tag/trunk" under them.  Or, perhaps the Eclipse project itself should be organized differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any answer would be subjective, so here's mine:

All 5 of your Eclipse projects would be trunks, with their own branches and tags.  You can put all of the project trunks under a folder in Subversion, so you and others know they relate to the same product.

Comment: Yeah. That's what I've decided to do yesterday. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to use one trunk/ for all of your projects.  Here is how I laid out my eclipse plugins and I followed some examples of other major eclipse plugin projects like JBoss tools when I created my structure.

/trunk/eclipse/plugins/Plug-in 1
/trunk/eclipse/plugins/Plug-in 2
/trunk/eclipse/features/Feature 1
/trunk/eclipse/features/Feature 2
/trunk/eclipse/releng/Update Site

And then you would have your corresponding 
/branches/1.0.x/eclipse/...
/tags/1.0.0/eclipse/...

This way when you create a tag you are copying everything that is under the eclipse/ folder, all plugins, features, and the state of the update-site, since you likely want to tag the state of all the plugins and features at once and roll that out to the update-site, instead of tagging each plugin/feature separately.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I've look around and many plugins, such as subclipse and xtext, seem to have done it the way you describe. It's not bad the way I have it now since the codebase is not that big but I may switch over soon before it's too late.